# Unable to get the json data on Spinner in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android and having trouble with the JSON part...

I'm developing a app where I'm retrieving  the data from the database.
Although response is successful but the data isn't displaying on the spinner.

I can see the data is retrieved and can be seen in log.

Please help I can't see where am I wrong.

```
12959-13040/com.xlint.atish.nycx E/Response:﹕ > get_word_file_names.php
{"word":[{"id":"1","word":"Sachin.docx"},{"id":"2","word":"Disable right click java script--.docx"}]}
```

//Populating spinner

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i < files_name.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(files_name.get(i).getName());
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);


    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    dropList.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: How do you populate data to spinner?

Comment: Can you post the code used for the spinner?